# JQuery: form validation - not getting any results

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am trying to implement the simple form validation plugin found here: http://www.jquery4u.com/forms/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/

but I cannot seem to get it working.

I have a simple form:

```
<form id="signupform" name="signupform" action="page" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<input type="text" id="signupusername" name="signupusername">
<input type="text" id="signupemail" name="signupemail">
<input type="password" id="signuppassword" name="signuppassword">
<input type="text" id="signupfirstname" name="signupfirstname">
<input type="text" id="signuplastname" name="signuplastname">
<input type="checkbox" name="tandc" value="tandcyes"> I agree
<button type="submit" value="Signup" class="submit">Signup</button>
</form>
```

And the associated plugin script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#signupform").validate({
                rules: {
                    signupusername: "required",
                    signupfirstname: "required",
                    signuplastname: "required",
                    signupemail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    signuppassword: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    tandcyes: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    signupusername: "Please enter your User Name",
                    signupfirstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    signuplastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    signuppassword: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                    signupemail: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    tandcyes: "Please accept our policy"
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

But it will just not work.

Of course I have checked both the plugin and link to JQuery are present and correct. Nothing appears in the console either. It just doesnt seem to trigger.

Does anyone know whats going on?

Thanks!

Comment: create a jsfiddle with your example

Comment: just to confirm.. did you include jquery.js ...?

Comment: @Sudhir Yep I did. All other JQuery's working fine

Comment: @Floradu88 will do. Stand by

Comment: It's working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/ns3mg/

Comment: @muthu I dont understand...thats exactly what I have. Did you change anythign?

Comment: Post here the error from console of the browser

Comment: hey @MeltingDog use below answer and add script in your html head

Comment: I did not change anything.Is Validation working ? or you face any other problem

Comment: hey friend in your html checkbox validation is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have included 2 times the same script.

The functions in script with validation appear 2 times in the source. Which is rather hard for the browser to know which one to pick.

Check head for two scripts.

Please add all your inputs in the *form* they are not present in the form tags.

```
<form>
<input type=... />
<input type=... />
</form>
```

if you close the form before your inputs that is the problem.

Comment: Ah yes I see! I have removed the other one. Problem still persists but yes you are right

Comment: @MeltingDog please update the site in order to debug some more.

Comment: I have now - the 2nd script has been removed

Comment: uncomment the other form tag and comment the actual tag. submit is being executed for some unknown reason.

Comment: No inputs present in your form, which is correct to submit the form.

Comment: Sorry Im not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Whew! Got it! Thanks for that! Awesome spotting!

Answer (score 1):

use this page and its works

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<title>Basic jQuery Validation Form Demo | jQuery4u</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
(function($,W,D)
{
    var JQUERY4U = {};

    JQUERY4U.UTIL =
    {
        setupFormValidation: function()
        {
            //form validation rules
            $("#signupform").validate({
                rules: {
                    signupusername: "required",
                    signupfirstname: "required",
                    signuplastname: "required",
                    signupemail: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    signuppassword: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    tandcyes: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    signupusername: "Please enter your User Name",
                    signupfirstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    signuplastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    signuppassword: {
                        required: "Please provide a password",
                        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
                    },
                    signupemail: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    tandcyes: "Please accept our policy"
                },
                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
    $(D).ready(function($) {
        JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
    });

})(jQuery, window, document);
</script>

</head>
<body>

<h1>Basic jQuery Validation Form Demo</h1>

<!-- HTML form for validation demo -->
<form id="signupform" name="signupform" action="page" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

<input type="text" id="signupusername" name="signupusername">
<input type="text" id="signupemail" name="signupemail">
<input type="password" id="signuppassword" name="signuppassword">
<input type="text" id="signupfirstname" name="signupfirstname">
<input type="text" id="signuplastname" name="signuplastname">
<input type="checkbox" name="tandc" value="tandcyes"> I agree
<button type="submit" value="Signup" class="submit">Signup</button>

</form>
<!-- END HTML form for validation -->

</body>

</html>
```